# Keychain loses Bitbucket app password every time

Tags: macbook-pro, password, keychain, ventura, git

I create a new app password in Bitbucket when `git push` asks for the password, I paste it and use it. Then I see the bitbucket login entry in Keychain, the next day when I push again git asks for the password!

I go check the keychain and there is no bitbucket login entry. I even tried creating the login entry manually in Keychain, but still the key goes missing.

But both Github and Gitlab passwords are still stored even after months, but Bitbucket password is gone everyday. Every other saved password is there except bitbucket's.

I am not using SourceTree, I use git CLI. I have set `credential.helpler` to `osxkeychain`.

I am literally creating new app password in Bitbucket every time I push, and I don't want to save it anywhere else. What do I do?

I am using MacBook Pro 2018, MacOS Ventura 13.5, Keychain 11.0, Git 2.41.0